# Is there a way to pass a model from a view that is strongly typed to a List<object>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I had a view that was strongly typed to a list of models, is there a way I could get a specific model from that list to pass to my controller? I'm currently iterating through said list and spitting values out in a checkbox list. For example:

```
@model List<myModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "selectedStatusForm" }))
{
    <ul class="list-group">

        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item">
                @Html.RadioButton("reviewSelected", Model[i].ID.ToString())
                @Html.Label(Model[i].ReviewDate.ToShortDateString()) - @Html.Label(Model[i].TypeOfReview)
            </li>

            @Html.Hidden("ID", Model[i].ID.ToString()) // This persists
        }

    </ul>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" />
}
```

What I want my controller to look like:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(myModel model){}
```

In the above example I could use "reviewSelected" as a param and get just that value, but I'm not able to say "give me this dang model found at this radio button".

I'm not opposed to using ajax for this, but I was not successful serializing this to pass through. My model remained null.

Comment: Can you post the code for you `Model`?

Comment: Would viewing the model buy you anything? The model itself is pretty dumb, just a few basic fields.

Comment: Yeah it would be very helpful. For your data to pass from your `View` back to your `Controller` you will need the data your passing to match up with the parameters on your `Controller` method. I think that might be where your issue is, because if the parameters don't match correctly the data will come through as `null`.

Comment: I took another look at my model, and this time on the submit I added a @Html.Hidden("ID", Model[i].ID.ToString()) to the loop above, and ID persisted. Am I going to have to drop every field into a hidden field to persist the data? I have like 30 fields in this specific model. 

Also I updated the original post to show my hidden field addition.

Comment: Yes, you would need to have a field that matches up with all of the values on your `Model` for your submission to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just a single parameter `reviewSelected` not good enough, you might have to define a view model to wrap the list of `myModel` and the selected review identifier, i.e., `reviewSelected`.

NOTE: I just made up the class names.

### MyModel

```
public class ReviewTemplateViewModel
{
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReviewDate { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfReview { get; set; }
}
```

### Model that wraps a list of MyModel, and other properties

```
public class CreateReportViewModel
{
    public int ReviewSelected { get; set; }
    public IList<ReviewTemplateViewModel> AvailableReviewTemplates { get; set; }
}
```

### View

```
@model CreateReportViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("create", "report", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "selectedStatusForm" }))
{
    <ul class="list-group">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.AvailableReviewTemplates.Count; i++)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ReviewSelected, Model.AvailableReviewTemplates[i].ReviewId)
                <label>
                    @Model.AvailableReviewTemplates [i].ReviewDate.ToShortDateString()
                    - 
                    @Model.AvailableReviewTemplates[i].TypeOfReview
                </label>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" />
}
```

### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(CreateReportViewModel model)
{
    // model.ReviewSelected will give you the selected review id
    ...
    // and model.AvailableReviewTemplates will be NULL because
    // they are not in the input field. They're not carried over on form
    // submit.
}
```

Now if you want to save the information of all `AvailableReviewTemplates` so that you don't have to **refetch the list** after the post, you have to put them into hidden input fields.

```
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.AvailableReviewTemplates.Count; i++)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AvailableReviewTemplates[i].ReviewId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AvailableReviewTemplates[i].ReviewDate)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AvailableReviewTemplates[i].TypeOfReview)

                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ReviewSelected, Model.AvailableReviewTemplates[i].ReviewId)
                <label>
                    @Model.AvailableReviewTemplates [i].ReviewDate.ToShortDateString()
                    - 
                    @Model.AvailableReviewTemplates[i].TypeOfReview
                </label>
            </li>
        }
```

Or better

Use `ajax` to submit the form, i.e., use `Ajax.BeginForm()`. `Ajax.BeginForm()` does require `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` package.

```
@model CreateReportViewModel
@{
    AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnBegin = "onFormBegin",
        OnComplete = "onFormComplete"
        // There are more options
    };
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("create", "report", new { area = "" }, ajaxOpts, new { @id = "selectedStatusForm" }))
{
    ...
}

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            window.onFormBegin = function() {
                // define what you want to do before form post begins
                // i.e., spins loading icon?
            };

            window.onFormComplete = function(request, status) {
                // I have a response object returned from the controller in 
                // JSON format so that I can do these. It's up to you to 
                // define a response object from the controller.

                var response = request.responseJSON;
                if (response.isOK) {
                    ...
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'll add the option of doing this through an `Ajax` call:

## The Model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

## The Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
    {
        // ... controller logic here
        return View();
    }
}
```

## The Ajax/View

```
@model List<myModel>

<ul class="list-group">

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <li class="list-group-item">
            @Html.RadioButton("reviewSelected", Model[i].ID.ToString())
            @Html.Label(Model[i].ReviewDate.ToShortDateString()) - @Html.Label(Model[i].TypeOfReview)
        </li>

        @Html.Hidden("ID", Model[i].ID.ToString()) // This persists
    }

</ul>

<input type="submit" id="my-submit" class="btn btn-warning" />

<script>    
    $('#my-submit').on("click", function() {
        var modelObject = {
            "Name": $('#reviewSelected').val(),
            "Id": $('#ID').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"../Home/MyAction",
            dataType: "json",
            data: modelObject,
            error:function(eroor){alert("opps it broke");},
            success: function (data) {
                // do stuff with data
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather use a helper to serialise the whole thing into a single hidden field, as it shouldn't break when maintenance leads to adding some new fields to your model.

```
@Html.Hidden("model", new Microsoft.Web.Mvc.MvcSerializer().Serialize(Model[i]))
```

Then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult MyAction([Deserialize] myModel model)
```

Comment: hm controller doesn't see [Deserialize]. Where does it live?

Comment: Microsoft.Web.Mvc

Answer (score 0):

write `[HttpPost]` in Top of your Action Method in your Controller.

Now, When you submit your form, It will find and detect your Action Method and send form data (model) to it.